# How to specify the permissions of a subdirectory when using the tar task of ant in linux?

Tags: java, ant, permissions, tar

I am trying to compress files using ant's tar task. I want to create 755 permissions for files in the bin directory under jre.

The structure of the directory you want to compress is as follows:

jre
 |
 +-- bin
 |
 +-- lib
 |
`-- etc

The ant build.xml file looks like this:

```
<chmod file="${basedir}/jre/bin/**" perm="755"/>
<target name="dist">
    <tar destfile="${basedir}/jre.tar">
        <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/jre" />
    </tar>
</target>
```

However, if you unzip the tar file, the permissions of all files in the bin directory will be 644.
How do I create a tar file with permissions of 755 for all the files in bin, the jre subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!
I didn't know about `prefix` property what it do... sorry.

So, I changed `build.xml` like below:

```
<chmod file="${basedir}/jre/bin/**" perm="755"/>
<target name="dist">
    <tar destfile="${basedir}/jre.tar" prefix="jre" >
        <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/jre" >
            <exclude name="**/bin/**" />
        </tarfileset>
        <tarfileset dir="${basedir}/jre/bin" prefix="jre/bin" filemode="755" />
    </tar>
</target>
```

When I run the ant using above script then get the awesome result what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could try:

```
<chmod perm="755" type="file">
  <fileset dir="${basedir}/*"/>
</chmod>
```

This creates a fileset of the directory including all sub-directories and creates the permission for the fileset.

Comment: After bundling jre by tar via ant, and the user unzips the tar file, the permissions of the files in jre/bin directory will change to 644.